# Pyramidal marae on one of the Pacific islands

Tags: archaeology, monument, polynesia

About 10 years ago I saw some information on the Web that an ancient pyramid-like structure (marae) existed on one of the Pacific islands, but was demolished in the end of 19th century. There was even a photo of this pyramid. Unfortunately, now I cannot find this information anymore. Does anybody know, on which island this pyramid was, and where I can read anything about it? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This page on Wikipedia was the first I looked trying to find the answer.

Comment: Whatever comment you are saying no to has been deleted; please include any prior research you have done in the question body so we don't unnecessarily repeat the same work.

Comment: Are you referring to the one at [Mahaiatea](https://www.tahitiheritage.pf/marae-mahaiatea-papara/)? The text is in French, sorry. The building on the picture looks reasonably pyramid-shaped. According to [Sharp et al. 2010](http://www.pnas.org/content/107/30/13234.short) who have the same picture in the [online appendix](http://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/suppl/2010/07/07/1005063107.DCSupplemental/pnas.201005063SI.pdf) of their paper, the picture is an engraving published in 1799, based on a sketch by Captain Wilson who visited it.

Comment: 0range, thank you!
Exactly, it was Marae Mahaiatea.